# Any difference in performance in ehcache maxElementsInMemory and maxEntriesLocalHeap

Tags: ehcache, ehcache-bigmemory

I am using maxElementsInMemory in Ehcache, recently  I got to know that from 2.5 it's deprecated and maxEntriesLocalHeap is used.

Any performance enhancement in maxEntriesLocalHeap or just a change in name.

Answer (score 5):

This was just a name change to better indicate where the sizing was applied. The deprecated method, for the Java configuration, delegates to the new method so there is strictly no change performance wise related to that change.

Now between Ehcache 2.5, which is a few years old, and Ehcache 2.10 - the current Ehcache 2.x maintenance, there might be a number of performance improvements coming from different changes. I would recommend giving the latest Ehcache 3.x a try if you can update to that version.

Comment: I am trying to upgrade to version 3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42070863/ehcache-migration-from-2-6-to-3-00