# Ehcache migration from 2.6 to 3.00

Tags: caching, ehcache, hibernate-cache

I am trying to upgrade Ehcache for my Project from 2.6 to 3.0 version.

Any replacement for net.sf.ehcache.Element and CacheExceptionHandler.

Less documentation on Ehcache 3, Can anyone give some tips for upgrading Ehacahe to version 3.

Comment: What are the things to keep in mind while migrating ehcache 2.x to 3.x? I'm migrating from 2.4.2 to 3.4 (current version). Is there any major changes that I need to make in source code?

Comment: If you use Spring have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47562286/548473

Answer (score 11):

Ehcache 3 is by design a major rework of the APIs so there are indeed large differences with Ehcache 2.x.

- `net.sf.ehcache.Element` has been completely removed, the `org.ehcache.Cache` API is now closer (but not identical) to a `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap`. This means you simply `put(K key, V value)` and `V get(K key)` - no need for a wrapper object.

  - A consequence of that is that you can no longer set a per mapping expiration. However, a custom `org.ehcache.expiry.Expiry` can be configured which can have mapping specific answers.
- The concept of `CacheExceptionHandler` is gone. In Ehcache 3 the approach is that a `Cache` should never be the source of an exception. If a `get` fails, it is valid to return `null` as long as you always return that until the next `put`. If a `put` fails, there is effectively no difference with a valid `put` followed by immediate *eviction*. Ehcache 3 follows these principles. However there are cache setups, mostly around *cache-through* and *distributed* caches, where consistency can be a challenge. Expect a solution to this to come soon to the Ehcache 3.x line.

As for a more complete documentation on the topic of migrating from one to the other, that is indeed something that still needs to be done.

Comment: do you know what can possibly replace the management.Cache in Ehcache 3?